# Temporarily disable (ignore / not display) the animation on a complex QML component

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to temporarily disable (ignore / not display) the animation on a complex QML component until a certain point in time? And later activate the animation and work as usual.

For example. A complex page on QML displays the data of the object, there are many small animations. When changing a data object, these animations should be ignored.

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
        property variant cppViewModel: MyCppViewModel {
            onBeforDataObjectChanged: {

            }
            onAfterDataObjectChanged: {

            }
        }

    Rectangle {
        id: idRect1
        Behavior on x { NumberAnimation { ... }}
        Behavior on y { NumberAnimation { ... }}
        x: cppViewModel.dataObject.offsetX
        y: cppViewModel.dataObject.offsetY
        scale: cppViewModel.dataObject.scale

        Rectangle {
            id: idRect2

            width: cppViewModel.dataObject.width
            heigth: cppViewModel.dataObject.heigth
            Behavior on width { NumberAnimation { ... }}
            Behavior on heigth { NumberAnimation { ... }}

            ColumnLayout {
                Rectangle {
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 100 * cppViewModel.dataObject.width1
                    Behavior on Layout.preferredHeight { NumberAnimation { duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad; }}
                    //... Any number of children with animation
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PropertyAnimation { target: idRect1; property: "scale"; from: 0.9; to: 1.0; ... }
}
```

If the values of the properties of the current data object change, then animation is needed. If the entire object changes to another, then the animation needs to be blocked.

Comment: Hi, could you please ad some code, to help my imagination? But I think the answer will be **yes**

Comment: Added. In real code more than 2000 lines.

Comment: So it is about those `Behavior`s?

Comment: Question about animation. Example can be rewritten without Benaviors. That is, instead of them PropertyAnimation will be used.

Comment: It all depends on, what you use to start the animation, as the solution is, to  not start it. I hope I covered your cases in my answer. If not please tell me, which case, that can't be substituted by a solved way, I have forgotten.

Comment: Thank you. Most likely, you listed all the options for managing animation activity. I hoped that it was possible to disable the animation centrally without additional code in each element.

Comment: That would be quite a rare edge case that you want to disable *all* animations. The next one, asks for a way only to disable all `NumberAnimations`, the next one to disable all animations with a duration > 5000. And it would be that easy as you can use the `animationsEnabled`-approach to group together animations as you like. Of course you can also use a `Singleton` to define the `animationsEnabled`, and derive your own `Animations` to only run, when this is enabled. So you don't need to have code repetition. But you will face other limitations.

Answer (score 3):

To disable `Animation`s, there are various ways, and the right one depends on how the `Animation` is started.

- If the `Animation` is started by setting the [`running`-property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-animation.html#running-prop), you can simply add a `&& animationsEnabled`
  to the condition where `animationsEnabled` is a property, you have to define somewhere else and toggle it accordingly.
- If you use the function: `run()` to start your `Animation`, the solution is to *not do it*.
- If you use the `Animation` within a `Behavior`, you can use the [`Behavior`s `enabled`-property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html#enabled-prop) to deactivate the `Behavior` and its `Animation`.
- Finally, I can think of `Transition`s. Just as `Behavior`, [`Transition` has an `enabled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transition.html#enabled-prop)-property, to deactivate it.

I hope I have not forgotten a way to animate and you will find the appropriate solution for your problem!